# c# not downloading file in stand alone mode but works in debug mode fine

Tags: c#

good evening all,

i been working on a little downloader for my program only downloads the python installer small little things will be adding more over time,

however i have a issue when i run it in debug it works downloads fine

when i do it in the debug folder and run the exe without visual studio it load the update box but creates a file with 0 bytes and says when trying to load,

this is not compatible with your os

code i have.

```
    private string GetFileName(string url)
        {
            string[] parts = url.Split('/');
            string fileName = "";

            if (parts.Length > 0)
                fileName = parts[parts.Length - 1];
            else
                fileName = url;
            return fileName;
        }

        private String getFileName(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            string fileName = "";
            try
            {

                HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream rstream = res.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    fileName = res.Headers["Content-Disposition"] != null ?
                       res.Headers["Content-Disposition"].Replace("attachment; filename=", "").Replace("\"", "") :
                       res.Headers["Location"] != null ? Path.GetFileName(res.Headers["Location"]) :
                       Path.GetFileName(url).Contains('?') || Path.GetFileName(url).Contains('=') ?
                       Path.GetFileName(res.ResponseUri.ToString()) : GetFileName(url);
                }
                res.Close();
            }
            catch { }

            return fileName;
        }



        public async Task downloadupdate()
        {


            if(os == "x86")
            {
                filename = getFileName("https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/python-3.11.0-amd64.exe");
                string url = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/python-3.11.0-amd64.exe";

                lblfilename.Text = "File Name: " + getFileName(url);
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += wc_completed;
                    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
                    XtraMessageBox.Show(filename);
                    filename = "python.exe";
                    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), "C://Temp" + "//" + filename);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                filename = getFileName("https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/python-3.11.0.exe");
                string url = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/python-3.11.0.exe";

                lblfilename.Text = "File Name: " + getFileName(url);
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += wc_completed;
                    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
                    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), "C://Temp" + "//" + filename);
                }
            }


        }


        private void wc_completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _MessageResult.Instance.Append("Download Completed!");
            //unzipupdate(Tiaga_Res.unzipupdate = "fixes19.zip");
            //DirectoryCopy(Tiaga_Res.startpath + "\\fixes19\\", Tiaga_Res._bo3_root, true);
            //XtraMessageBox.Show("Applied Fix Aug And Reflex Sight Fix");
            // richTextBox1.Text = _MessageResult.Instance.Merge();
            Process.Start("C://Temp" + "//" + filename);
            this.Close();
        }

        void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBarControl1.Properties.Step = 1;
            progressBarControl1.Properties.PercentView = true;
            //progressBarControl1.Properties.Maximum = e.ProgressPercentage;
            progressBarControl1.PerformStep();
            UpdateProgressBar(e.ProgressPercentage);
            txtpercent.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";

            double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            lbldownloaded.Text = "Downloaded: " + bytesIn + "/" + totalBytes;
        }

        private void UpdateProgressBar(int value)
        {
            progressBarControl1.EditValue = value;
        }
```

screen shot of in debug.
[image: filename gen in debug]
[image: file downloading in debug mode]
[image: file failing to work in stand-alone mode]
any help would be much appreciated i cant see it would be a libz issue i used that since day one to compile dlls into my project never had this issue before

Comment: `catch { }` - that's not a good start, in terms of trying to work out what's going on. Catching an exception and swallowing it with no logging at all makes it *much* harder to understand problems.

Comment: I'd also suggest that having two methods named `getFileName` and `GetFileName`, each of which accepts a URL, but which behave *massively* differently, is going to make your life much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `DownloadFileAsync` and then immediately disposing of the `WebClient` you're doing it with. That's probably a bad idea - but it's been *ages* since I've used `WebClient`. (I'd strongly advise using `HttpClient` instead, along with async/await.)

Comment: Check your release and try toggling between x64 and x86 builds to see if there's a difference. Your x86 case looks like it's using the AMD64 and the else case looks like it's not. Did you mean for that to be the other way around? Why not just check for that condition and update the path alone since the rest of code is the same?

Comment: to be honest i never really done a lot with httpcliant and i not done a lot with downloading this is all quite new have read up on it a lot but people all seem to use webclient i will try and do what you suggested and see if i can resolve

Comment: You should probably await the `DownloadFileAsync` method by using the `await` keyword.